# How to use strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to generate active classes from url segments

Tags: php, navigation, strpos

We've found a lot of answers for this but don't fully understand them (or the `strpos` manual page) so sorry if this is already answered.

---

#### Setup:

Consider the following urls...

```
http://www.domain.com/whats-on/show-name/   
http://www.domain.com/whats-on/show-name/events
```

And how we're applying the `.active` class in the following list item markup...

```
<li>
    <a class="<?= (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/whats-on') === 0 ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?= $ShowWhatsOn; ?>">What's on</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="<?= (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/events') === 0 ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?= $ShowEvents; ?>">Events</a>
</li>
```

---

#### Issues:

1. What's On gets the active class on the What's On page but also on the Events page because /whats-on is also in the url: /whats-on/show-name/events
2. Events never receives the active class

---

#### Question:

1. How do we get strpos to check specific url segments so the `.active` class is applied on the correct page?

We're trying to keep this short for the menu markup so hopefully there's a way to do this on one line?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: Try checking for `show-name/events` when you want to check for `/events` ?

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard  Thanks heaps. I can see that `PHP_URL_PATH` will get the path but I don't understand how to get a specific segment within the path. e.g. get segment one or segment three? Do you have to create your own function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) gives you the position of a string (needle) in another string (haystack). So by doing

```
strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/whats-on') === 0
```

You are checking if the `REQUEST_URI` starts with "/whats-on" (is at position 0). Since both URLs start with "/whats-on", the first item will always be active and the second never.

One fix would be to add a check for "/events":

```
<li>
    <a class="<?= (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/whats-on') === 0 && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/events') === false ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?= $ShowWhatsOn; ?>">What's on</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="<?= (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/whats-on') === 0 && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/events') !== false ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?= $ShowEvents; ?>">Events</a>
</li>
```

Although this gets a bit verbose for your template, so you may want to break the logic out into a function like `isActive()`.

Comment: Cheers, will create a function for this

Answer (score 0):

OK, for my future reference (and others) this is how I solved it.

#### 1. Make two functions

I made this in the /helpers/ directory of my CMS and called it npe_nav.php (if using the Concrete5 CMS, don't name the file navigation.php as that name is taken by c5 so didn't work for me).

```
// Get URL segments
public function getURLSegments() {
    return explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
}

// Get a specific URL segment
// Takes a number which corisponds to a segment in the URL e.g. consider:
// http://www.domain.com/whats-on/show-name/events
// $navHelper->getURLSegment(1); will return whats-on
// $navHelper->getURLSegment(3); will return events
public function getURLSegment($n) {
    $segs = $this->getURLSegments();
    return count($segs) > 0 && count($segs) >= ($n-1)?$segs[$n]:'';
}
```

---

#### 2. Load the function in your template

In Concrete5, I loaded it like this (package-name refers to the package this tools is saved in within the CMS):

```
// Load nav helper
$navHelper = Loader::helper('npe_nav','package-name');
```

---

#### 3. Call the function in your template

For the URL: http://www.domain.com/whats-on/show-name/

This also checks if the third segment is null before applying `.active` because `/whats-on/` appears in all URLs in this section - so don't want it to be active on other pages.

```
<li>
    <a class="<?= (($navHelper->getURLSegment(1) == 'whats-on') && (is_null($navHelper->getURLSegment(3))) ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?= $ShowWhatsOn; ?>">What's on</a>
</li>
```

For the URL: http://www.domain.com/whats-on/show-name/events

And other pages at segment 3

```
<li>
    <a class="<?= ($navHelper->getURLSegment(3) == 'events' ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?= $ShowEvents; ?>">Events</a>
</li>
```